# Create AWS::Pinpoint::PushTemplate using CF template

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-pinpoint

Hi I want to create AWS::Pinpoint::PushTemplate using cloudformation template and I am following this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-pinpoint-pushtemplate.html.

```
Type: AWS::Pinpoint::PushTemplate
Properties:
  Default:
    Action: OPEN_APP
    Body: FirstName - {{firstName}}, LastName - {{lastName}}
    Title: Title
  DefaultSubstitutions:
    firstName: default
    lastName: default
  Tags:
    project: project
    tashi: "Pinpoint Template"
  TemplateName: template_name
```

I am getting type validation error for`DefaultSubstitutions: `Property validation failure: [Value of property {/DefaultSubstitutions} does not match type {String}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to docs [DefaultSubstitutions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-pinpoint-pushtemplate.html#cfn-pinpoint-pushtemplate-defaultsubstitutions) is a `String`.

However, in your case, you set it up as map:

```
  DefaultSubstitutions:
    firstName: default
    lastName: default
```

Maybe have to try using it as json string:

```
DefaultSubstitutions: "{\"firstName"\:\"default\", \"lastName"\:\"default\"}"
```